# Java sleep commands ignore commands before the sleep

Tags: java, android

I have a button on an activity, when I click it I want the button to change colour, wait some time and then change colour again.

I have tried the following two versions of the sleep:

Attempt 1:

```
public void buClick(View view) {
    Button buCard = (Button) view;
    buCard.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

    TimeUnit time = TimeUnit.SECONDS;
    try {
        time.sleep(2);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    buCard.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
}
```

Attempt 2:

```
public void buClick(View view) {
    Button buCard = (Button) view;
    buCard.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    buCard.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
}
```

With both methods the result is the same:

- button is clicked
- button's background remains as the default
- the app waits for 2 seconds
- the button's background changes to red

At no point does the button turn green; what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: that could be  expected behavior, as the UI will be updated the next tick after you set background, and you put the main thread into sleep (which you should never do BTW)

Answer (score 1):

Do not block your UI thread. Use a handler instead.

If you are trying to block your main thread the whole UI thread would stop causing your app to freeze, once your sleep is over you are calling setBackgroundColor(Color.RED). And the red color gets applied that is why you are not able to see the change of green color.

If you use a handler like the below case which wont block the UI thread you should be able to see the color change.

Read about why you should not block your UI thread here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

```
    Button buCard = (Button) view;

    buCard.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable r=new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           buCard.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);           
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(r, 2000);
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you (I needed to do "final Button buCard..." but other than that it was perfect!